# How to build a cpp module on a cmake project?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm using cmake and it's a wonderfull tools. I'm using it under Linux with the Ecplise IDE. But, there are something I could do easily when I was working on Windows through Visual Studio, and I don't know how to do it with cmake :

I want to build the ".o" of a single ".cpp" file of my project. I can't find a way to do that easily (i.e. without invocate gcc directly).

I tryed the following command line

```
make CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/module.cpp.o
```

But I doesn't work... Have you got any idea how to do that ?

Comment: That's doesn't answer to my problem...

Comment: Ah i didn't realize that you wanted to do this as a one-off and not as part of the build (the object library builds the .o files of the sources without linking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write

```
make module.cpp.o
```

in the build directory (where you have executed cmake)